# Unpleasant null cells in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dbnull, complex-networks

I wrote 2 functions in C# that print  some data in a WinForms DataGridView control. But as I shown highlighted cells in image; there are some unpleasant null cells.
I wrote this code:

```
    public DataSet ds = new DataSet("network_dataset");
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public void printToDatagridView() // 1th function to print
    {
        dt.Columns.Clear();
        dt.Rows.Clear();

        dt.Columns.Add("Node", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Opinion", typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < NOV; i++) 
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Node"] = network_array[i, 0];
            row["Opinion"] = network_array[i, 1];
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
    public void printToDatagridView_update(int k)//2th function to print update 
    {
        DataRow row;
        dt.Columns.Add("Iteration " + (k + 1), typeof(int));

        for (int i = 0; i < NOV; i++) 
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Iteration " + (k + 1)] = network_array[i, 1];
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
     }
```

Now how can I print my rows in one row or how can I remove null cells?

Comment: When you are updating why are you adding new rows?  You added a new column correctly.  Now you just want to put values in new column (not new row).

Comment: Can you explain how can I put data in new column?

Comment: First remove row = dt.NewRow();.  Then change : dt.Rows[i]["Iteration " + (k + 1)] = network_array[i, 1];

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 functions in C# that print some data in a WinForms DataGridView control. But as I shown highlighted cells in image; there are some unpleasant null cells. I wrote this code:
[null cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9VJC.png)